# Sending data from Server to Client

Tags: java

I want to send data from server to client when server is updated. Normally client sends a request to server and server response to the client. Is there any way to send data to a specific client directly?

Pls guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be after what is known as [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology):

> Push, or server push, describes a style of Internet-based
>   communication where the request for a given transaction is initiated
>   by the publisher or central server. It is contrasted with pull, where
>   the request for the transmission of information is initiated by the
>   receiver or client.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898066/java-push-from-server-to-clients) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698739/server-side-push-with-java) previous SO posts seem to discuss what you are after.