# WebSockets vs BOSH

Tags: websocket

I need to establish a server to server communication over WAN.  Server A may be behind the firewall. For security purpose, only server A can initiate request to server B in order for server B to respond back to server A.

What're the pros and cons between Websockets vs. [Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP (BOSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH)?

I did some search on this topic, but all seem to compare them in the context of UI being involved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434088/why-isnt-bosh-more-popular-especially-as-an-alternative-to-websockets-and-long?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet?rq=1 (a bit dated, but still related)