# Want to implement web client chat into XMPP ejabberd server same as facebook

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, ejabberd

Hi I have installed XMPP ejabberd server into local machine to chat between two or more computer with the Gajim application.
It is working perfectly.

But Now I have requirement to implement the such type of chat into my website where people communicate with each other.

I don't have Idea too much in eJabber server So can you please help me out?

I have using Laravel php as backend, javascript, Angular js for front end and for Mysql for database.

Please suggest me to how I will start this implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

**Server:**
You should look into Ejabberd [WebSockets](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration#modhttpws) and [Bosh](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration#modhttpbind) feature. Do your research before choosing one. Checkout [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434088/why-isnt-bosh-more-popular-especially-as-an-alternative-to-websockets-and-long), it might help.

**CLient:**
There are many XMPP JavaScript library available i.e [Strophejs](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs), [JsJac](https://github.com/sstrigler/JSJaC) etc. Choose any one as per your requirement.

Comment: So if I will use Stropjejs, Can I save the chat history into database ?

Comment: Sure you can. Do checkout mod_mam https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#modmam

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have explored some documentation.

Comment: But I want to know If I will implement the things from server side So Strophejs is required or not ?

Comment: what are u asking about the web chat or message archiving? For web chat you need both server side & xmpp client both. Message archiving has nothing to do with xmpp client lib. So not required at all.