# what is the difference between websocket and BOSH(Bidirectional streams Over Synchronous HTTP)?

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmpp, strophe.js

Actually i'm trying to integrate chat application in web application.

I found that we can use XMPP server(as application protocol) and web socket or BOSH(as transport protocol).But i got stuck in choosing the transport protocol why i should choose web socket over BOSH or vice-versa.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Xmpp over websockets. xmpp is a protocol designed for messaging and presence. So for chat application is easier to use xmpp. Bosh is a long polling request that is supported for older browsers, if you are targeting new browsers is better to use xmpp over websockets.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i know that what i don't is the main difference between these two Transport Layer Protocol (BOSH and web socket), or just browser compatibility is the main difference

Comment: You will probably get the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434088/why-isnt-bosh-more-popular-especially-as-an-alternative-to-websockets-and-long